Getting error 500 when adding "import vertexai" line in Google AppEngine python service
I am trying to deploy a flask app that calls the "gemini-1.0-pro" model.
My requirements.txt file:
Flask==3.0.0
openai==1.25.1
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.20.0
google-cloud-aiplatform==1.49.0
vertexai==1.49.0
# protobuf==3.19.6
pandas==2.2.2

My app.yaml file(with some values modified a bit):
runtime: python39

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /.*
  script: auto

env_variables:
  AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_4: "gpt-4-testing"
  AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT_4: ""
  AZURE_OPENAI_VERSION_4: "2023-05-15"
  AZURE_OPENAI_4_KEY: ""
  VECTOR_API_ENDPOINT: "581192819.europe-west3-863223216184.vdb.vertexai.goog"
  VECTOR_INDEX_ENDPOINT: "projects/863223216184/locations/europe-west3/indexEndpoints/8845104852527742976"
  VECTOR_DEPLOYED_INDEX_ID: "ai_test_vector_search_index_ht_05041804"
  PROJECT_ID: "ai-test"
  LOCATION: "europe-west3"

During debugging, I identified that the "import vertexai" line triggers the 500 status code.
I used the following simple code to test:
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    print("Here")
    import vertexai
except Exception as e:
    logger.error("An exception occurred:" + str(e))

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def root():
    return "Hello World!"

The developer console in google chrome return no content when the error 500 occurs.
I found in some links the suggestion to add the protobuf in the requirements.txt, but it didn't change anything.
In another thread people were suggesting to pull the docker image locally and investigate.
I pulled, and started the container two times, once without the "import vertexai" line, and one time with.
I entered the docker container and ran the "curl 0.0.0.0:8080" command.
In both cases, while inside the docker container, I get the "Hello World" string as a response, but only in the browser, the status 500 code was visible when the import vertexai was there.
One other mention is that the logs of the app log only error 500, without any details:
2024-05-10 22:00:33 default[20240510t235715]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500
Between gunicorn and the browser, I think nginx is used.
Can anyone point in a direction I could investigate, or maybe have a solution for the problem.
Thank you very much!

Please include your app.yaml in your question. Your requirements.txt doesn't include a WSGI runtime (e.g. gunicorn) that will run your app.  See Python runtime for more details.
